# Телеграмм бот не отвечает на сообщения после скрытия кнопок

Tags: python, telebot

Написал небольшого бота для телеграмма с помощью библиотеки telebot и создал там небольшую клавиатуру с которой можно взаимодействовать для получения id и имя, а так же написал код, отвечающий на определенные слова пользователя. Проблема в том, что после скрытия кнопок бот не отвечает на мои сообщения. ЧТо делать? (не знаю как понятнее объяснить)
import telebot
import configure
from telebot import types

```
client = telebot.TeleBot(configure.config['token'])

@client.message_handler(commands=['get_info', 'info'])
def get_user_info(message):
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='ДА', callback_data='yes')
    item_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='НЕТ', callback_data='no')

    markup_inline.add(item_yes, item_no)
    client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Хотите кое-что узнать?', reply_markup=markup_inline)


@client.callback_query_handler(func= lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    if call.data == 'yes':
        markup_reply = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        markup_id = types.KeyboardButton('МОЙ ID')
        markup_user_name = types.KeyboardButton('МОЕ ИМЯ')
        markup_hide = types.KeyboardButton('СКРЫТЬ КНОПКИ')

        markup_reply.add(markup_id, markup_user_name, markup_hide)
        client.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Нажмите на одну из кнопок', reply_markup=markup_reply)

    elif call.data == 'no':
        client.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Ну как хотите')

@client.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_info_user(message):
    if message.text == 'МОЙ ID':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Твое id: {message.from_user.id}')
    elif message.text == 'МОЕ ИМЯ':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Твое имя: {message.from_user.first_name}')
    elif message.text == 'СКРЫТЬ КНОПКИ':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'пока', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(), parse_mode='Markdown')


@client.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_message(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'привет':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ну здарова, отец')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'как дела':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ну нормально как видишь')


client.polling()
```

Answer (score 1):

Не требуется описывать несколько обработчиков, попробуйте так:

```
@client.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_info_user(message):
    if message.text == 'МОЙ ID':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Твое id: {message.from_user.id}')
    elif message.text == 'МОЕ ИМЯ':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Твое имя: {message.from_user.first_name}')
    elif message.text == 'СКРЫТЬ КНОПКИ':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'пока', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(), parse_mode='Markdown')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'привет':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ну здарова, отец')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'как дела':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ну нормально как видишь')
    else:
         client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'я вас не понимаю')
```